# Django - Connect to post_init signal on model change form only

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to use a `post_init` signal connection on a model instance to call a remote API which will fetch some data and then use this as a sort of dynamic model property that gets assigned to that instance when the change form is loaded.

Specifically, I have another system that uses a completely different framework that has a model that is (mostly) the same as a model I have in Django. The `post_init` signal should check the remote version to see if there are any images saved to it, and then assign this boolean as a dynamic model property to the Django model instance.

This would give me a condition to check during the model's `post_save` signal that I can use to determine if I need to upload images to the remote model or not.

Since this will be calling a remote system, I don't want the API call in `post_init` to be called for every single model instance when loading the admin model list page, I only want it to happen on the change form.

**How can I exclude this expensive API call from all `post_init` signals except for when it is triggered from the model instance's admin change form?**

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correct, you need to make the API call when post_save is emitted. you have the option to check if the instance is created or updated.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Your Model)
def upload_image(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
        #This will check if the instance is created or updated
        if created:
            #upload the image or do any api calls
            #update your dynamic field on the instance
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This way you will be making only one API call after creation. If you want it to happen only during updates, just change the condition to

```
if not created :
```